# Block Office application from connecting to certain Sharepoint 2010/2013 lists and libraries

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I'd like to prevent Office applications from being able to connect to certain SharePoint 2010 Lists.

For example, let's say I have a SharePoint list that I don't want users to be able to edit data in it using MS Access for instance.

Is this possible? I was not able to find anything about this subject.

Answer (score 2):

I think the better approach would be to grant users read only access to the list. Then even if the connect the list to an Office app or download the data for offline use, they won't be able to change it.

If that isn't feasible or desirable, you should be able to create a custom permission level that you can apply to specific lists that has the use client integration features unselected. This should make it so that client office applications cannot be used.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I really need to know if one is able to limit access sharepoint lists in such a way that ONLY the web forms are used for editing and not Access,Excel etc.

Comment: I've come accross installations, where some lists use complex workflows that must fire upon new/changed items. In some cases, when a user connects to such a list with Access for example, he's able to rapidly edit many rows of data which results in the server going balony because of the sudden load. Begin able to achieve my goal would be less costly than throwing hw at the problem and/or redesigning the solution. thx again :-)

Comment: edited with another option to try

Comment: +1 for custom permission level, probably the simplest method to implement.

Comment: Interesting 2nd option @PirateEric . I'll definitely check this out and come back.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to turn off the the two following user permissions at the web application level in Central Admin.

Use Remote Interfaces (un-checking this removes both automatically)
Use Client Integration Features.

That removes the ability do connect through office for ALL users.  Very helpful if dealing with an Internet facing environment.